# rake db:create (or migrate) blows up on me when entering command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rake

I've been having this problem for over a week now. When I do a rake db:create or a rake db:migrate I get this long list of errors like:

.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR

It has one for MAJOR, MINOR, BUILD, NUMBERS, VERSION...and it goes on and on ending in:

rake aborted!
stack level too deep

I just did a gem install rake and that didn't fix the problem. Help is much, much appreciated!

Comment: try `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: Bundler works by managing gem versions. If your application is expecting Rake 0.8.7 and you have Rake 0.9.2 installed (and you do) then when you run `rake command` you're running 0.9.2. When using bundler, though, it uses the version specified in your Gemfile. So `bundle exec rake command` runs Rake 0.8.7.

Comment: @coreyward Is there a way to get my Gemfile Rake version up to 0.9.2

Comment: Yes, but Rails still doesn't like it. You'll want to check for help on getting Rails working with 0.9.2, but the rake upgrade itself is simple, just run `bundle update rake`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Copied from comment to question to make the question answered

Answer (score 1):

Glad it worked... Corey answered it why it works.. He's absolutely correct.

```
   bundle exec rake db:migrate
```